# how to convert camel case to snake case with vanilla emacs

Tags: text-editing

When editing for example a ruby file,
can't emacs toggle CamelCase to snake_case out of the box?

Example ruby file

```
  def SecDecGov
    puts "abort"
  end
```

Comment: AIK there is no such function out of the box.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/9288181 describes similar question with useful answers.

Comment: There is also [Glasses Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GlassesMode) which displays CamelCase symbols in more readable ways.

Comment: even with prelude extensions ..

Comment: See the [`string-inflection`](http://sodaware.sdf.org/notes/converting-to-snake-case-in-emacs/) package.

Comment: The [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/) has a large page on [CamelCase](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CamelCase).